# Problem displaying the mysql content in Paragraphs

Tags: php, mysql, html

I insert questions(which might be a few paragraphs) in a sql table using php and than i diplay them on a webpage.

but when i display the question it loses its formatting. I mean it will just show the whole question in one paragraph, even thou there were many paragraphs before.

```
<td width=\"700px\" bgcolor=\"#EAD57F\"><font color=\"#4A2A0B\">Question :</font><font color=\"#5E450B\">".$row2['Question']."</font></td>
```

$row2['Question']  --> is my question that i am getting from my sql table by running the SELECT query.

So if i post something like :
a
s
d
f

into my input box.

the output looks like : asdf

How should i resolve this?

Best
Zeeshan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you storing them as plain text, or do they contain HTML tags?  If they are stored as plain text you should put them in a <pre> tag or something equivalent in order to preserve the spacing.  Alternatively, you could do the encoding into HTML, putting in <p> tags and such where necessary, but that is complicated and easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You probably save your paragraphs separated by a "new line" character. To translate that in HTML check the [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) PHP function (in HTML new line is the `<br />` tag).